# Single Sign On for Intranet with Vaadin & Springboot - security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, active-directory, certificate, vaadin7

We have a Vaadin / Spring Boot application which should be accessible via a browser and without login from intranet only.

We would like to implement SSO with the Windows login (Active Directory).
The goal is high security with least configuration as the application is sold to customers.

I came up with the following scenario:

1. receive the IP address of the client accessing the Vaadin-Application.
2. Look up in the Active directory / Domain controller, which is in RW mode and see which user is online with this IP address in this very moment.
3. check the rights of this user managed by the Active Directory Groups.
4. make application available with logged in user for the client requesting it.

   - IP spoofing is not possible (as the connection is bidirectional, also users have no access to network devices.)
   - this login process is only done once to initiate the session.

Am I correct with these thoughts? Can you see any security issues? Is it *really* necessary to use certificates?

What would you recommend if so? Kerberos, CAS, x509, SAML?